# Blocking queue consumers and race condition

Tags: java

I have an application which would be recieving stock prices from an external system continously.

The prices will be keyed by the stockID.

As the prices arrive, they will be fed to a blocking queue.

There will be a pool of threads which will consume and process from this queue and put the prices in a cache(hashmap of stock id and price).

What bothers me is if the queue has prices for duplicate stocks id's, when the threads process these, it is possible that the older price is written to the cache after the newer.

Is there anyway to get around this scenario?

How can I make sure that the latest is processed last?

Comment: Do you have control over the "StockPrices" object? Meaning is this an object that you can manipulate the fields and methods of?

Comment: since this is coming in from an external system,I do not have control over it.

Comment: What about wrapping the object to add fields or methods?

Comment: The object does have a timestamp on it which the thread can check before updating the cache but that doesn't look very elegant,does it?

Comment: Does it have a timestamp linked with it?

Answer (score 1):

You could tag every incoming price update with an automatically-incremented sequence number. When writing to the cache, you could drop every update whose sequence number is lower than the one already in the cache for that stock.

Alternatively, you could partition your stock universe across threads, meaning that updates for a given stock are always processed by the same thread.

Comment: aah , I like the partitioning approach.Any sample code that shows how to do it?

Comment: @user1736924: One queue per worker thread (where each thread would be assigned a set of stocks to handle). The code that accepts incoming message sticks every message into the correct queue. If you decide to take this approach, you'll need to give some thought to load balancing.

Comment: Page 92 JCiP, LinkedBlockingDeque (work stealing approach)